# CSSグリッドの角括弧で囲まれた部分の意味と使い方はどのようなものなのでしょうか？

Tags: html, css

[grid-template - CSS: カスケーディングスタイルシート | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template) に下記のコードがありました。

> ```
> #page {
>   display: grid;
>   width: 100%;
>   height: 200px;
>   grid-template: [header-left] "head head" 30px [header-right]
>                  [main-left]   "nav  main" 1fr  [main-right]
>                  [footer-left] "nav  foot" 30px [footer-right]
>                  / 120px 1fr;
> }
> ```

にある、`[header-left]`や`[footer-right]`の意味はなんなんでしょうか？どういう用途でつかっているのでしょうか？
おそらく上記リンク先に解説が書いているのかもしれませんが、構文に慣れておらず、どのあたりに解説記事が書かれているのかわかりませんでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

同 MDN のページには、 `grid-template` プロパティの構文について以下のように書かれており、角括弧とその内容は **[grid ライン](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Glossary/Grid_lines)の識別子**であることがわかります<sup>[[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template#Formal_syntax)</sup>。このような記法について、 MDN の[名前付きグリッド線を使用したレイアウト](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Layout_using_Named_Grid_Lines)という記事にて詳細が記述されています。

> #### 正式な構文<sup>[[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template#Formal_syntax)</sup>
>
> ```
> none | [ <'grid-template-rows'> / <'grid-template-columns'> ] | [ <line-names>? <string> > <track-size>? <line-names>? ]+ [ / <explicit-track-list> ]?
> where
> <line-names> = '[' <custom-ident>* ']'
> ```